# Access shadowed variable from subroutine?

Tags: abap

How to call a shadowed variable from subroutine?

Below is code sample, where I do want to print shadowed variable value:

```
data i type i value 13.

perform _form.

form _form.
  data i like i.
  i = 17.

  " write shadowed i value here
endform.
```

Comment: Don't give a variable the same name in the subroutine, than in the main program. Use different names or prefixes (gv_ in the main program and lv_ in the subroutine)

Comment: you can also add the global variable as parameter to the form and give it another name, e.g. p_i. In general your code would be much better readable if you use different prefixes for global and local variables. This would be the best practice solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a possibility to do it dynamically with `ASSIGN ('(PROGRAMM)VARIABLE') TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<lv_fs>)`.

Here's an example.

```
REPORT zz_test.

DATA i TYPE i VALUE 13.

PERFORM _form.

FORM _form.
  FIELD-SYMBOLS <lv_shadow> TYPE i.
  DATA i LIKE i.
  i = 17.

  " write shadowed i value here
  ASSIGN ('(ZZ_TEST)I') TO <lv_shadow> CASTING.
  IF <lv_shadow> IS ASSIGNED.
    WRITE <lv_shadow>.
  ENDIF.
ENDFORM.
```

Comment: Thank you. So at the syntax level there is no other option and this is the only way?

Comment: I have never seen anything else that would enable you to read the variable with the same name in global context, but I cannot assure you there is no other way.

Comment: @J3W The best option would be to avoid shadowing in the first place. Which you can by avoiding global variables whenever possible. And if you *have* to use global variables, then avoid name clashes by giving them more descriptive names than `i`.

Comment: @Jagger: From your example casting is not necessary, as the types are same.